# mklink: How do you make a symbolic link to a file in command prompt when the file aready exists?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, symlink, mklink

Coming from a unix-based environment, I expected to be able to create symbolic links in a Windows 7 command prompt using mklink or a similar function.  Indeed, I find that I can do this, but if the link already exists, I find I cannot overwrite the link with a 'force' option, as you can in unix with `ln -sf`.

Is there a way that I can create a symbolic link with the same name and overwrite any existing link, all in one command?  I'm surprised that the list of options here doesn't allow this, from what I've seen.

Comment: Why does it need to be one command?

Comment: I work in a development group with multiple configurations for our application.  As a result, whenever we want to reconfigure the application we repoint the symbolic link to the appropriate configuration file.  In linux, you can easily overwrite an existing symbolic link with a new one by adding the -f flag, but in Windows, apparently you can't.

Comment: In Windows, you can easily overwrite an existing symbolic link by deleting it and then creating the new one.  The only difference is it takes two commands rather than one to do it.  I'm asking why the extra command matters to you.

Comment: I like thinks to be concise.

Comment: You'll need to use a third-party solution, then, or write your own.

Comment: @HarryJohnston it's called atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to overwrite an existing symlink using the `-Force` argument:

> New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "/existing/symlink/path" -target "/new/target/path" -Force

Comment: +1, but since it came up in the comments above, note that this probably isn't atomic at the file system level.